# How to assign this data string to Tuple in C#?

Tags: c#, tuples

I want to know how I could assign the following return values ((image name, [X_cord,Ycord, radius] from circle detection function) to a data structure that I have defined.
My return data stream is as follows : (square bracket are seperated with "\r\n".

```
"C:\stars\d7_fr_bfdf_c0_non_201218_200822_hm_0_d.jpg , [[[278 734  33]
  [396 380  33]
  [396 616  32]
  [748 734  33]
  [750 262  33]
  [630 616  33]
  [160 144  32]
  [514 260  34]
  [ 44 498  33]
  [514 498  33]
  [280 262  33]
  [512 734  32]
  [632 144  33]
  [280 498  32]
  [630 380  33]
  [ 44  26  33]
  [ 44 260  34]
  [398 140  36]
  [752 500  34]
  [514  26  33]
  [160 380  32]
  [158 616  36]
  [ 42 736  33]
  [750  24  34]
  [276  26  32]]]"
```

I want to assign return values to follow data structure :

```
public class CircleCordinates
{   // Do not change the order
    [DataMember]
    public string image { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Tuple<double, double, double>> circle { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best way to do it ?

Regards,
Pubudu

Comment: @Rand Random Surely you would do CircleCordinates.circle.add(new Tuple<double, double, double>{276, 26, 32).

Comment: @nickgowdy don't think I do

Comment: Unfortunately, circle detection happens in Python script. I could not get done in OpenCV in C#.

Comment: Do you want to deserialize that string?  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Consider using the new [Value Tuples](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your string into a const string:

```
private const string StringToParse = 
@"C:\stars\d7_fr_bfdf_c0_non_201218_200822_hm_0_d.jpg , [[[278 734  33]
  [396 380  33]
  [396 616  32]
  [748 734  33]
  [750 262  33]
  [630 616  33]
  [160 144  32]
  [514 260  34]
  [ 44 498  33]
  [514 498  33]
  [280 262  33]
  [512 734  32]
  [632 144  33]
  [280 498  32]
  [630 380  33]
  [ 44  26  33]
  [ 44 260  34]
  [398 140  36]
  [752 500  34]
  [514  26  33]
  [160 380  32]
  [158 616  36]
  [ 42 736  33]
  [750  24  34]
  [276  26  32]]]";
```

And wrote this function:

```
 private const string MyPattern = @"\[\s*(?<x>\d{1,3})\s+(?<y>\d{1,3})\s+(?<r>\d{1,3})\]";
 private static readonly Regex MyRegex = new Regex(MyPattern);
 public static CircleCordinates ParseIt()
 {
     var firstSplit = StringToParse.Split(',');
     var path = firstSplit[0].Trim();
     var data = firstSplit[1];

     var matches = MyRegex.Matches(data);
     var circle = new List<Tuple<double, double, double>>();
     foreach (var match in matches.Cast<Match>())
     {
         var tuple = new Tuple<double, double, double>(
             double.Parse(match.Groups["x"].ToString()),
             double.Parse(match.Groups["y"].ToString()),
             double.Parse(match.Groups["r"].ToString()));
         circle.Add(tuple);
     }

     var result = new CircleCordinates {image = path, circle = circle};
     return result;
 }
```

It seems to work.